# highcharts only one label is getting displayed

Tags: highcharts

Only one label is displaying on xAxis categories.
Lable "Jan" is displaying but no other label shows up.

Chart type is: Column

xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }

Comment: You'll probably need to create a  full example for this to make any sense.

Comment: What is your full chart config object?  What does your data look like?